# Logging from APIM to Event HUB seems not working properly

Tags: azure, logging, azure-api-management, azure-eventhub

I've followed instructions in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs).

I've created an **Event Hub** namespace that hosts an hub called `clicks-hub` secured by a policy called `ClicksLoggingPolicy` with **Send** claim only.

Then I've added the logger to my APIM service using this URL:
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/MY_SUBS/resourceGroups/MY_RESGROUP/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/MY_APIM/loggers/clicksLogger?api-version=2019-12-01

with this payload:

```
{
    "properties": {
      "loggerType": "azureEventHub",
      "description": "Logger for click events",
      "credentials": {
        "name": "clicks-hub",
        "connectionString": "Endpoint=sb://myapim.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=ClicksLoggingPolicy;SharedAccessKey=****************"
      }
    }
}
```

After sending the **PUT** request I got `201 created`.

I've configured an APIM API with this POST operation. It follows the XML policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <log-to-eventhub logger-id="clicksLogger">@( "LOGGING_FROM_AZURE_APIM" )</log-to-eventhub>
        <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I triggered various requests using the APIM **Test** panel and I can see requests on **Metrics**:
[image]

but nothing where when I quert the hub:

```sql
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [OutputAlias]
FROM
    [clicks-hub]
```

[image]

I tried to ingest some test data using [this tool](https://github.com/devigned/testhub) and I can see the messages.

Any idea about what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance to anyone who'll try to help.

Regards, Giacomo S. S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can only query when the **EventHub** message is an object / is JSON:

From this policy

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <log-to-eventhub logger-id="kai-logger">@( "LOGGING_FROM_AZURE_APIM1" )</log-to-eventhub>
        <log-to-eventhub logger-id="kai-logger">@( "{'message':'LOGGING_FROM_AZURE_APIM2'}" )</log-to-eventhub>
        <mock-response status-code="200" content-type="application/json" />
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

only the messages with `LOGGING_FROM_AZURE_APIM2` show in the query.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm still unable to see results in the Query panel. As before I see the successful requests. Btw, now I'm sure messages are sent. I'll try to check using an EH Trigger.

Comment: "Test query" also did not work for me. But hitting the "Refresh" button.

Comment: ...and did you create the Namespace "myapim" and also the EventHub "clicks-hub" in the Portal?

Comment: all resources are provisioned, I've the apim and the event hub resources. EH namespace contains event hub "clicks-hub"

Comment: It was my fault, sorry. I didn't saved the modified policy. I can see JSON messages in Query panel and ALL messages in my test EH Trigger.